# Need a UDP terminal program

Tags: terminal, udp

Does anyone know of a good UDP terminal program that will accept somewhat large strings of hex numbers and send them to a pre-defined address? I'm developing a Netburner controller and I need a Windows UDP terminal to send raw hex data, NOT ascii - no more than 20 bytes at a time, but it has to be able to send them all at once when I hit the send button. The Netburner UDP Terminal is great if I'm only working with ASCII, but I'm not.

Answer (score -1):

install perl (look for Strawberry Perl or ActiveState Perl) and then you can do:

```
perl -MIO::Socket -e 'IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => "1.2.3.4", PeerPort => 1234, Proto => "udp")->print("\x01\x02\x03")'
```

should be possible with python and other scripting languages too.
Also you might use netcat, which should also be available for windows.